# AJAX request url not not as expected

Tags: jquery, ajax

Whenever I make a jquery ajax post request it appends the url specified to the my pc's ip address.

What am I missing here?

[image: error]

The request code.

```
var data = {
    "operation": "shutdown"
}

$.ajax({
    url: "127.0.0.1",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    complete: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log("Error: " + err);
    },
    data: JSON.stringify("Test")
});
```

I'm sure this is something fundamental but I am not sure how to find a solution for something like this as I wouldn't even know what to look for.

Comment: Try with `url: "http://127.0.0.1"`.
JSON.stringify converts an object to literal object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the url does not start with "http://" it is being interpreted as a relative path.  Just put in "http://127.0.0.1/" if that is what you want.

NOTE:  Since your actual page is loading from "192.168.0.14:3000" you will get a cross origin security error unless you turned CORS on.  Also, "http://127.0.0.1/" will request on port 80, and not the 3000 that your original request was made to.

Comment: This is embarrassing. I spent way too long on this. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

replace url: "127.0.0.1" with url: "/"